# 403 Forbidden for personal blog

Tags: html, web

I brought a personal blog website theme from themeforest. I can open it from my own computer, but after I uploaded to my host, I got

> 403 Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /~username/index.html on this
>   server.

I have no idea what could be the error source, so I don't know what more info I need to provide. Please help me and I can provide more codes/info if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a file named index.html uploaded?

Comment: Yes. I do have a file named index.html

Comment: When you "uploaded it", how did you do so? Web based service? FTP? Do you know the permissions you set on it? Also, I don't think this is a programming question. Superuser is likely a better fit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for support on a commercial blog theme. You should talk to the software authors.

Comment: I am sorry for posting an off-topic question here, I didn't realize that. Sorry about it. And I used scp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

smells like a file permission problem:

assuming you uploaded using FTP, or SCP, or similar, and didn't set the files to be readable by everyone the web-server may not be able to read them.

Comment: Thanks. I used scp. How do I change it so it's readable by everyone?

Comment: log in using ssh and issue `chown -R o+r .` in the appropriate directory. or use a GUI tool like filezilla,

Comment: You mean I should use filezilla to transfer the files? I did that but still getting 403 forbidden. Thanks.

Comment: Oh. Ok. I think I've found where to edit permissions. Thank you so much.